# PHP Loading login files into a div without reloading url

Tags: php, html, mysql

How would I be able to load all my login/profile.php files into one specific div without affecting or reloading the rest of my website? I have thought of using $_GET variables to keep the parent url the same and I have used this same tactic for my navigation menu where all my pages load in my #back_drop div.

Below I put together a very basic version of what my site looks like and as you can see the #side_panel is where I would like all my login/profile files to load into while the nav, content, and footer is unaffected by what the #side_panel does. I want to be able to login, logout, get errors, reset password, etc inside this div without it reloading the main portion of my site.

I have an **index.php** file which is my main index with includes for my header, aside, content, and footer and then I have an entire folder for my php files relating to my login form and other files that will load into my main content page. I didn't want to separate each include so I have them below with comments before each include noting that they are separate so you can see what I am working with.

I am currently loading my login files using an iframe because it is the simplest way to get what I am looking for but have found it very irritating at times especially when I logout and pages requiring to be logged in are still present unless the page is refreshed which seems to be a major security issue.

I have tried to use an include function into my #side_panel but if I attempt to login in, it either won't connect or will end up logging in through the parent url depending on how I edit my login.php file. I am thinking of using $_GET variables but am not sure if that would be a security issue if the variables are in the url but cannot think of any other way

**index.php** <-- My main index page

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['page'];

if (!$page) {
    $page = 'Home';
}

include('includes/header.php');

echo "<div id='back_drop'><div id='content'>";
include('php/'.strtolower($page).'.php');
echo "</div></div>";

include('includes/footer.php');

?>
```

**aside.php** <-- where my login/profile files are included from

```
<iframe src="php/index.php" height="500px" width="100%" style="position: relative; border:none;"></iframe>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show_login").click(function(){
    $("#side_panel").toggle("slide");
    $("#side_panel").toggleClass("slide");
    $(this).find('img').toggle();

    if ($("#side_panel").hasClass("slide")) {
      $("#back_drop").animate({'padding-left': '0'}, 300);
    } else {
      $("#back_drop").animate({'padding-left': '230px'}, 300);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    outline: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    background-color: #CCC;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

header, nav, section, aside, footer, article {
    display: block;
}
#big_wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

#top_header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #262626;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    background-color: #404040;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 2px 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    z-index: 9999;
}
#back_drop {
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 230px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#content {
   border: 5px solid red;
   height: 500px;
}
#show_login {
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
#show_login:active {
    width: 23px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-right: 1px;
}
#side_panel {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #a19b9b;
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 54.491px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    z-index: 9999;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.slide {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
#main_section {
    clear: right;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#bottom_footer {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #404040;
}
```

```html
<!-- header.php -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id='big_wrapper'>
    <header id='top_header'>
     <nav id="navigation">
        <div id="show_login">
         <button>Show</button>
        </div>
        <div id="main_menu">
        <!--Navigation header menu
        <?php
         $sections = array('Home','nav1','nav2','nav3','nav4','nav5');

         foreach($sections as $row) {
            echo "<li id='menu_list'><a href='index.php?page=$row'&login='$login'";

           if ($row==$page) {
              echo "class='active'";
              }
              echo ">$row</a>";
             }
         ?>-->
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>

<div id='side_panel'>
    <div id='login_contain'>
    <!-- aside.php -->
    #side_panel<br>
    Where my login/profile pages load in
    </div>
</div

<!-- This is what is actually in my code. Commented to show in snippet
<?php
   echo "<div id='side_panel'><div id='login_contain'>";
   include('includes/aside.php');
   echo "</div></div>";
?>
-->

<div id='back_drop'>
    <div id='content'>
    #back_drop<br>
    All my navigation links load only in this div by using href='index.php?page=(($_GET['page']))' and if I could do the same thing maybe for my #side_panel to include all my login/profile pages
    </div>
</div>

<!--footer.php -->
<div class="footer_nav">
   <!--Navigation footer menu
   <?php
     $sections = array('Home','nav1','nav2','nav3','nav4','nav5');

     foreach($sections as $row) {
       echo "<li><a href='index.php?page=$row'>$row</a></li>\n";
              }
       ?>
        -->
</div>
<footer id='bottom_footer'>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Couple things here:**

1. You will want to use AJAX for this, an iFrame is not suitable for your needs
2. Not sure how much of your dynamic page system is represented in your sample script but you should check on your page call on the `$_GET`, that method can be dangerous if someone tests your `$_GET` and includes a page that shouldn't.

**/index.php**

```
<?php
# Create an allow array (or have these in a database)
$public = array(
    'home',
    'about'
    'contact'
);
# Check that it's not empty. If not empty, make sure it's allowed. Use home as default
$page = (!empty($_GET['page']) && in_array(strtolower($_GET['page']), $public))? $_GET['page'] : 'home';
# Include normally
include('includes/header.php') ?>

<div id='back_drop'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id='content'>
        <?php include('php/'.$page.'.php') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- add jquery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    // On clicking the menu link
    $('li > a').on('click',function(e){
        // Stop the link from reloading page
        e.preventDefault();
        // Create ajax
        $.ajax({
            // Send request as GET
            'type': 'get',
            // Send to the index page
            'url': '/index.php',
            // equivalent of ?page={pagename}
            'data': {
                'page': $(this).attr('href')
            },
            // When request comes back, find the content and place just the content
            // into this page's content
            success: function(response) {
                // "response" is what is coming back from the ajax all
                // Find the content from the returned html
                var getContent = $(response).find('#content').html();
                // Place it into this page's content id
                $('#content').html(getContent);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php include('includes/footer.php') ?>
```

Comment: I guess AJAX is the best way for accomplishing what I am trying to do, seems to come up a lot in my search and I do not like using an iframe or object. I figured using $_GET would be a major security issue especially when dealing with login scripts so I will definitely look at your code above and experiment what works for me.